# different condition depending on parameter

Tags: javascript

How to optimise processAllJobs function for that two cases (fixAllJobs, logAllJobs).

```
processAllJobs = (channel) => {
    const jobsCopy = [...this.getState().jobs];
    let validJobs = [];
    jobsCopy.forEach((job) => {
        if (channel === 'fixJobs') {
            if (job.processStatus !== ERROR && job.processStatus !== FIXED) {
                job.processStatus = IN_PROCESS;
                job.progress = 0;
                validJobs.push(job);
            }
        }  else {
            if (job.processStatus !== ERROR) {
                job.processStatus = IN_PROCESS;
                job.progress = 0;
                validJobs.push(job);
            }
        }
    });
    this.setState({isRunning: true, jobs: jobsCopy});
    ipcRenderer.send(channel, validJobs);
};

fixAllJobs = () => {
    this.processAllJobs('fixJobs');
};

logAllJobs = () => {
    this.processAllJobs('logJobs');
};
```

I just came up with this, but this is complete nonsense. Is it a good approach to write ternary operator in if condition?

```
if (channel === 'fixJobs' ? job.processStatus !== ERROR
&& job.processStatus !== FIXED : job.processStatus !== ERROR) {
      job.processStatus = IN_PROCESS;
      job.progress = 0;
      validJobs.push(job);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the condition `job.processStatus !== FIXED` to be checked only if channel is `fixJobs`, you can write the condition as below to achieve that

`job.processStatus !== ERROR && (channel !== 'fixJobs' || job.processStatus !== FIXED)`

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason in future you add a new code/status/Etc., you can use an array

```
let status = ["ERROR"]
if (channel === 'fixJobs') status.push("FIXED");

if (!status.some(s => s === job.processStatus)) {
    job.processStatus = IN_PROCESS;
    job.progress = 0;
    validJobs.push(job);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the loop as below:

```
jobsCopy.forEach((job) => {
        if (job.processStatus !== ERROR) {
            if ((channel === 'fixJobs' && job.processStatus !== FIXED) || channel === 'logjobs' ) {
                job.processStatus = IN_PROCESS;
                job.progress = 0;
                validJobs.push(job);
            }
        }
    });
```